# C++, class as parameter to a method, not template

Tags: c++, class

So, I came across an interesting method signature that I don't quite understand, it went along the lines of:

```
void Initialize(std::vector< std::string > & param1, class SomeClassName * p);
```

what I don't understand is the "class" keyword being used as the parameter, why is it there? Is it necessary to specify or it is purely superficial?

Comment: I saw this as well in a class member declaration and I was going crazy trying to find out what it meant.
`class Foo{
private:
  class Bar* pointerToBar;
}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a forward declaration of the class.  It is the effectively the same as

```
class SomeClassName;
void Initialize(std::vector< std::string > & param1, SomeClassName * p);
```

There are many situations in which a forward declaration is useful; there's a whole list of things that you can and can't do with a forward declaration in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration/553869#553869)).

Comment: does it act as forward declaration then?

Comment: "but you need to use a pointer or reference to an instance of the class" -> If you just have a non-definition function declaration like in this case, you can go fine with value-parameters, though.

Comment: interesting, I have never seen a forward declaration inside a function parameter before.

Comment: @Remy:  To tell the truth, I've _never_ seen this done before in real code either.  @Johannes:  Yeah; I posted the link to the list of what can and can't be done because I knew I'd forget something.

Answer (score 1):

It's not superficial.  It allows you to specify "SomeClassName" as a parameter even if "SomeClassName" hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: does it act as forward declaration then?

Answer (score 1):

Most superficial. In C, when you define a struct:

```
struct x { 
    int member;
    char member2;
};
```

To use that, you have to use `struct x whatever`. If you want to use `x` as a name by itself (without the `struct` preceding it) you have to use a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct x { 
    int member;
    char member2;
} x;
```

In C++, however, the first (without the `typedef`) has roughly the same effect as the second (both define `x` so you can use it by itself, without `struct` preceding it). In C++, a `class` is essentially the same as a `struct`, except that it defaults to `private` instead of `public` (for both members and inheritance).

The only place there's a difference is if there is no definition of the `class` in scope at the point of the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

it is the same as you write:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

as

```
int i; 
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

the class declaration is a definition  and a pointer to it

Comment: the scope of the variable i is different.

Comment: Does not answer the original question.